# Getting signature error while installing a different version of the app

Tags: file-system, system, 7.1-nougat, system-apps, telegram

Recently I install a custom ROM named eelo https://e.foundation/. It comes with pre-installed Telegram app. After much research I was able to uninstall if from the system with the command `adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 org.telegram.messenger`. But when I tried to install the new apk with `adb install telegram.apk` I got the following error

```
adb: failed to install telegram.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package org.telegram.messenger signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

I also tried uninstalling with this `adb uninstall org.telegram.messenger` but it gave out `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]`.
With further research I found out that I can install the new `.apk` with different if I comment the section in `/data/system/packages.xml` referring to `telegram`. But after making the change when I reboot it get back to the unedited version.

Currently using Android Nougat 7.1.

Can anyone tell me the reason as to why this happens and how I can stop it from happening? And how would I be able to install a different version of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately found an answer to the query and how to solve it.

1. The first is how to delete a system application completely?
   These are the following steps

   `$ adb root`  - To start adbd with root privileges.

   `$ adb shell` - To interact with the phone system directly.

   `$ pm uninstall --user 0 <package>.apk` - To uninstall the package from the root    user  is any package you want to remove from the system.

   These few steps may remove the whole package but in my case it was different as it  left behind few files from the previous built app. So these were the steps that I followed :

   `$ adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system` - This would remount the system as read-write. Originally `/system` is a read-only folder so you can't edit directly.

   `$ adb shell rm -r /system/<package>.apk` - This would remove the apk and there won't be anything left from the previous built.
2. Why I couldn't edit the `/data/system/packages.xml` file?

   The answer to this is that though I can edit it with `vim` but it kept reverting back to the previous unedited form. This was happening because it was updating the information from `/system/app` files. Thus, editing it went in vain.

Refer to the following links that actually helped me out

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android

https://www.besttechie.com/remove-preloaded-software-from-android/

Answer (score -2):

Try using an apk Cloner if you want to reach to your goal fast.
using https://appcloner.app/
you can change the package id of your new telegram version and install it manually

Comment: That isn't really the answer to my problem or the issue I'm facing. Diversion to a problem can't be considered as a solution. Your suggestion gonna work to a limit but still the files of the previously installed telegram app would be there and I won't be able to appreciate that.